# Don't understand how this output came about

Tags: python

```
def perform_magic(first, second):
       third = first[0]
       first[0][0] = 5

       second.append(third)
       second[1][1] = 8
       second.append([6,7])

first = [[3,4]]
second = [[1,2]]

perform_magic(first, second)

print(first[0])
print(second[2])
```

Output:
[5,8]
[6,7]

When i executed 'second[1][1] = 8' this also changed the value in first[0][1] from 4 to 8. Why?

Comment: Because `third` is the first element of `first`, which you append to `second`. You then modify that element `second[1][1] = 8` since `second` only had one value, and the value you added was the same object that was in first.

Comment: Read the following: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga ah i see thanks for ur explanation!